# alien conversion from deb to rpm on fedora 27

Tags: fedora, rpm, conversion, deb, alien

I find myself unable to convert a .deb package to .rpm to install it on fedora. I am not able to download the equivalent rpm file, so conversion is my only way out. I get this error after using the prompt alien -r package.deb as su.

```
Package build failed. Here's the log of the command (cd shadow-beta-0.8.62; rpmbuild --buildroot='/home/user/shadow/shadow-alpha-artful(1)/shadow-beta-0.8.62' -bb --target x86_64 'shadow-beta-0.8.62-2.spec'):
Fehler: Zeile 5: Leerer Tag: Summary:
Für folgende Zielplattform(en) wird gebaut: x86_64
```

Edit: I am unable to follow the suggestions in the answers. How can I edit a file that is not even generated because the conversion failed?

Comment: `alien --to-rpm --generate package.deb` This should generate the source, and you can rebuild the package using `rpmbuild -bb <packagename>.spec"` after you edit the spec file.

Answer (score 0):

The tag named `Summary` in the RPM spec file is empty, but it is not allowed to be empty.

alien gets this information from the original deb, which means it must be missing there.

You can always edit the generated spec file and build the RPM yourself.

Comment: An answer explaining how to do what you suggest would have been more helpful.

Comment: @DavidMulder What exactly do you want help with?

Comment: I think it would be more helpful to say, run `alien -r -g -v myproject-1.0.deb`, with the -g parameter creating the package directory. Then modify the spec file and build the rpm with rpmbuild, etc. Your answer simply says "edit the generated spec file and build the RPM yourself".

Comment: And now I see someone mentions this (--generate) in the comments to the original question :-/
I came upon this question after encountering the same problem. Your answer pointed me in the right direction, but left me fumbling to find the correct parameters to do what you suggested.